# Authenticating .apk downloads

Tags: android, iis, apk, authentication

Am trying to deploy an apk file from a webserver (IIS6), I have the mime type configured correctly and all is working when the folder allows anonymous access.  However, I would like to force a challenge/response for the download of the .apk.  Even with clear text authentication set on the folder and/or .apk file, no mobile device is being challenged for access to the file and because of this fails to d/l the file.  When trying to access the file from a desktop browser I get challenged as expected.  Is this capability not supported in the Android OS?  Have been trying this with different 2.x Android versions but not ICS as of yet on both tablets and phones.

M

Comment: aside: the android browser has issues with downloading files protected via .htaccess password prompting. (ie. it will work for .html, and other browser-opened files, but as soon as it tries to download it doesn't do the authentication properly).

Not sure if this is related to your problem or not. :S

Comment: Have you tried other browsers on the mobile device?

Comment: not yet, but doing that now..good suggestion

Comment: Unfortunately still no joy - Tried Dolphin HD with the same result.  IIS shows a 401 and phone browser does not throw up a challenge screen when going directly to the file.  Even if I hit a htm page with a link to the APK first I get challenged for the htm page (200), but fail the apk download (401) when I click the link.  IIS shows no userid info for the request

Comment: Just tried Firefox browser and it works, allowing me to download and install the authenticated file.  So it appears that the answer is to use Firefox?

Comment: yes?! :D ...God I hate mobile browsers...
I wish I had more experience with this so I could give you a more conclusive answer :(